# Sql Server : Column wise total SQl Query

Tags: sql

Is it possible to get column wise total using query?
in my grid there are 20 columns. i have to display each columns total value in its footer. now im using TemplateField field and javascript function to get the total value.if it is possible to get it from sql query i can reduce the code

Comment: It would be nice if you specify the reason for down voting.

Comment: You can have the sum of each columns value inside sql. Please see the answers.

Comment: The best option here would be to use the Grid you're using to calculate and display those totals - don't do it in SQL. You cannot select your actual data and all the totals in one SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT *, SUM(SalesAmount) OVER() as TotalSales
FROM YourTable
```

But if you only need the sum and nothing else, just do:

```
SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) as TotalSales
FROM YourTable
```

And in future, please try to give more information in your question.

Rob

Comment: sorry... in my grid there are 20 columns. i have to display each columns total value in its footer. now im using TemplateField field and javascript function to get the total value.if it is possible to get it from sql query i can reduce the code..

Answer (score 1):

To sum columns, it's best to use whatever client you're dealing with (Reporting Services, Datagrid, whatever), and just tell that to display a totals row.

If you were to do it within the same query, then you'd end up with rows that meant something different, and displaying it becomes quite awkward.

You CAN do it in the query, but you probably shouldn't.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for ***SUM*** function

Eg:

```
SELECT SUM(salary) as "Total Salary"
FROM employees
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX([p-1]) p1,MAX([p-2]) p2 from #temp
```